# How to open/run/control an .exe application using Matlab on windows OS?

Tags: matlab

I want to run/ control an external `*.exe` application using Matlab.

I need to pass some commands on open `.exe` or control some `button clicks on .exe`

I used `system('*.exe')` to open th application.

But, I want to then give commands from Matlab to the application like:

Prompt on the application: `Enter Y or N:`

In this case, I want to use Matlab and enter `Y` or `N`.

Other requirement:

Prompt on application: select a `file` and click `OK`?

I want to supply filename like `file.txt` and click `OK` using Matlab.

I heard actxcontrol or something like this is used for this but not able to find examples of this specfic needs.

Any help,

Thanks,

Gopi